# Falcon + uwsgi do not see changes on a Fysom state machine

Tags: uwsgi, python-3.5, state-machine, falconframework

I have a falcon project who makes use of a Fysom state Machine. The SM change state based on informations from the outside. The SM is created at the app launch and passed to a view as an argument.
At some point I'm waiting  for a user event to go in a certain state, which is sent through the API to trigger a SM event.

Problem I have is that when launched with uwsgi the view is not aware of the current state of the state, it considers it's still in its initial state, so I cannot go to the desired state.

The problem does not happen with wsgiref.simpleserver.

I there a way to make the view aware of the changes on the SM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be related to this:

> The SM is created at the app launch and passed to a view as an argument.

Are you sure you still have a reference to the object, or does uwsgi do a copy of the object in each view ?

You could have a look to:
- [uwsgi shared memory](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SharedArea.html)
- [uwsgi caching](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html)

Answer (score 2):

Singleton design pattern, see here: 
http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html